# Why isn't my SQL Server 08 Maintenance plan running at all?

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008, scheduled-task, maintenance

I have this maintenance plan scheduled on my SQL Server 08... however, it never runs!

It's been setup for 2 weeks now and I have not seen a single backup created, what am I doing wrong? How do I get this thing to run the backups and other tasks?

[image]

Comment: What does the maintenence plan history show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the SQL Server Agent service is running.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure the SQL Server Agent services is started, check these:

- Make sure that the job is enabled.  Maintenance plans create SQL Agent jobs which you can look at via SQL Server Management Studio.  You can easily check the SQL Agent to make sure the job is enabled.
- Make sure the schedule in the job is enabled.  Schedules themselves can be disabled independent of the job they belong to.
- Review the job history to see if the job is running and actually succeeding.
- If you're confident that everything is enabled and started, then if you have cleanup tasks associated with your job check the retention parameters in the cleanup task to ensure that they are not set to delete the backup(s) that were just done in your maintenance plan.